# Questions on array operations in R

Tags: r, arrays, performance, for-loop, mapply

I frequently come up with a problem, where I want to modify, say, a column in an array based on information on another array, but I don't know how to do these sort of problems, efficiently avoiding for loops.

To give an example, here is a reproducible R code for a maximization and mass transfer problem using 3D arrays. The code works fine, but the nested loop at the bottom is too slow for my purposes.

The question is, whether there is a way to improve its speed, e.g., by using mapply. I haven't been able to do so this far.

```
# Initialize parameters


N = 11
I = 3
P = 10


# Initialize some random-ish inputs


prob = runif(P)
prob = prob/sum(prob)

alpha = array(0, c(N,I))

for (i in 1:I) {
  alpha[, i] = (1-seq(0, 1, 1/(N-1)))/i
}

f0 = array(runif(N*I), c(N,I))
f0 = f0/(rep(1,N) %*% t(colSums(f0)))
obj = array(runif(N*N*I*P), c(N,N,I,P))


# Initialize the arrays needed in the solution


maxmat = array(0, c(N, I,P))
inds = array(0, c(I*N, 3, P))
p0 = array(0, c(N,I))
arr = array(0, c(N,I))


# Solve a maximization problem 


maxmat = apply(obj, c(1,3,4), function(x) which.max(x))


# How do I improve the performance of the below code?

for (i in 1:I) {
  for (p in 1:P) {

    p_tmp = 0 
    p_tmp = prob[p]*rowsum(f0[,i], maxmat[, i,p])

    p0[as.numeric(attributes(p_tmp)$dimnames[[1]]),i] = p0[as.numeric(attributes(p_tmp)$dimnames[[1]]),i]+ p_tmp[,1] 
    arr[,i] = arr[,i] + prob[p]*alpha[maxmat[,i, p],i]*f0[,i]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop can be fully vectorized using `outer` and `rowSums` (with the `dims` argument) and adjusting the `maxmat` indices to correspond with `i`. The vectorized solution is ~18 times faster.

```
fp <- outer(f0, prob)
mm <- maxmat + rep(rep(seq(0, (I - 1L)*N, N), each = N), P)
p02 <- matrix(rowsum(c(fp, numeric(N*I)), c(mm, 1:(I*N))), N, I)
arr2 <- rowSums(fp*alpha[mm], dims = 2L)
```

Check that the results are the same:

```
all.equal(list(p0, arr), list(p02, arr2))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Benchmark with `N = 110`, `I = 30`, and `P = 100`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  vectorized = {
    fp <- outer(f0, prob)
    mm <- maxmat + rep(rep(seq(0, (I - 1L)*N, N), each = N), P)
    p02 <- array(rowsum(c(fp, numeric(N*I)), c(mm, 1:(I*N))), c(N, I))
    arr2 <- rowSums(fp*alpha[mm], dims = 2L)
  },
  loops = {
    for (i in 1:I) {
      for (p in 1:P) {
        p_tmp = prob[p]*rowsum(f0[,i], maxmat[, i,p])
        p0[as.numeric(attributes(p_tmp)$dimnames[[1]]),i] = p0[as.numeric(attributes(p_tmp)$dimnames[[1]]),i]+ p_tmp[,1] 
        arr[,i] = arr[,i] + prob[p]*alpha[maxmat[,i, p],i]*f0[,i]
      }
    }
  }
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
#>  vectorized  12.7971  17.76585  18.83623  19.4157  19.87045  33.4201   100
#>       loops 213.0616 333.43520 348.48067 366.3358 382.36215 422.4743   100
```

A little explanation about `c(fp, numeric(N*I))` and `c(mm, 1:(I*N))`: appending `N*I` zeros (whose groups are `1:(I*N)`) to the end of `fp` ensures that `rowsum` returns a vector of length `N*I` so we don't have to initialize `p0` or mess with `dimnames`.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. Would you happen to know a faster solution for the maximization, which creates the maxmat matrix? That's by far the slowest part of my code, and too slow at the moment. I am using N=1000, I=10, and P = 10 for now, although might like to increase N to 2000 and P to 100 (if memory allows).

Comment: Can you change how you're creating `obj` so that it is the same as `matrix(aperm(obj, c(2:1, 3:4)), N, N*I*P)`? If so, `array(colMaxs(obj), c(N, I, P))` will return `maxmat` about 25 times faster.

Comment: Thanks! I would actually also need the indices, which maximize the objective function, i.e. the output of which.max(), even though I did not include in the above code. colMaxs() would not give this, correct? Is there some other way to speed up the code here to also give this?

Comment: By default, `Rfast::colMaxs` returns the row index of the maximum value for each column. Set the `value` argument to `TRUE` to get the column maximum. See `?Rfast::colMaxs`.

Comment: IOW,  `maxmat <- array(colMaxs(matrix(aperm(obj, c(2:1, 3:4)), N, N*I*P)), c(N, I, P))` is compatible with your current code. The problem is that the `matrix(aperm(` operations slow it down, so if you can build `obj` so that it matches `matrix(aperm(obj, c(2:1, 3:4)), N, N*I*P)` with your current `obj`, it will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks! I think this should be doable, at least at the cost of readability. I will look into this.